# msal-browser, 2.0: logout() logs met out of O365 on the web, including outlook

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

When I call `agent.logout(...)` with the account that I logged into my application with, I get logged out of my application but I am also logged out of Outlook on the web that I have open in another tab.

How do I logout of only my application (registered in AAD 2.0 of course) but *not* logout of  Outlook on the web? I provide the "account" that I logged in with that should be tied only to my specific application.

Comment: Are these two accounts the same underlying AAD account?

Comment: They are the same AAD account in the sense that they are the same UPN. It is 2 different applications though.  I have to login to both Outlook (o365) to use office on the web as well a separate login for my application (registered in AAD).

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior, given both applications rely on the same AAD session. If you would like to only remove the session information for the MSAL instance on your website, you can manually clear local/session storage, instead of using the MSAL logout API (which will send the user to the AAD logout screen).

If you would like the ability to configure logout to only clear browser storage and not making a network request to the AAD logout page, you can open a [feature request](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/new?assignees=&labels=feature&template=feature_request.md&title=) on the MSAL.js Github repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think that makes sense. I guess I'm not familiar with how AAD sessions overlay/influence the oauth process. I'll open up a feature request. Thanks